# Drone.io do not trigger git push

Tags: docker, drone.io, gitea

I am trying to add a dockerized drone.io to join my existing gitea (also in docker container)

Drone is working and see each of my repo. I enable drone on one of them called my-app for the test.
As drone need a file called .drone.yml, I created one & filled it with some basic code to use pipeline & start some tests

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: test
  image: maven:3-jdk-10
  commands:
  - mvn install
  - mvn test
```

Finally I have push it but nothing seem to happen on drone

Here is how I stared my containers

```sh
docker run \
  --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --volume=data:/data \
  --env=DRONE_GITEA_SERVER=https://... \
  --env=DRONE_GIT_ALWAYS_AUTH=false \
  --env=DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY=2 \
  --env VIRTUAL_PORT=80 \
  --env VIRTUAL_HOST=my.domain \
  --env LETSENCRYPT_HOST="my.domain" \
  --env LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL="me@email.com" \
  --restart=always \
  --detach=true \
  --name=drone \
  drone/drone:1
```

```sh
docker run --name git -v /home/leix/gitea:/data -e VIRTUAL_PORT=3000 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=other.domain -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST="other.domain" -e LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL="me@email.com" -d gitea/gitea
```

I expect drone to run test on git push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution but I don't know why it's working but I used Docker-Compose instead of docker run & it's working pretty well